# Are there any website comments systems available (like phpbb for forums)?

Tags: html, web, comments, threaded-comments

I'm looking to add comments to my website. I've seen some great frameworks for forums (like phpbb) and for blogs (like wordpress). Is there anything like this for comment systems?

Comment: But what features/tools are you looking from it? You're way vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into [IntenseDebate](http://intensedebate.com/) and [Disqus](http://disqus.com/), which I believe are hosted solutions.

Comment: are there any that are not hosted?